# How to write an IIF statement with or error?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I Have an iif statement which has to filter the data for both years 2019/2020 and 2020/2021:

1. `=IIf((Parameters!Year.Value <> "2020/2021") and (Parameters!Year.Value <> "2019/2020"),True,False)`
2. `=Parameters!Year.Value <> "2020/2021" or Parameters!Year.Value <> "2019/2020"`

These 2 statement works for me in SSRS but when deployed it says:

> Error: subreport could not be shown.

I also tried:

```
=Parameters!Year.Value <> "2020/2021"
```

When deployed this works well and no errors in deployment. I don't understand what is the issue here.
Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the deployed reports and redeploying.

If you have changed the default parameters in your report design these will not get updated in the deployed report so I find it;s easier to just delete the reports and redeploy.